# Is there a property in angularjs form to get only the changed values?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to submit only the user modified data in an Angular Js form. How do we do it in Angular Js? (Version: 1.4.14).

I've come across the property `$$success.parse` of form. But there is no details about this property in Angular Js website. Can we use this property? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be looking at the `$dirty` property of the `NgModelController`s tied to the form elements.

Comment: Read [AngularJS ngFormController API Reference - $getControls method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$getControls) and [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, you want to check `$dirty` property of each form element. 
See example here https://next.plnkr.co/edit/YW7ad8vYjfE9jnLW?preview

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-cloak>
  <form name="userForm">
    <div>
      Name:
        <input
          name="name"
          type="text"
          ng-model="user.name"
          ng-change="getChanges(userForm)">
      Age:
        <input
          name="age"
          type="number"
          ng-model="user.age"
          ng-change="getChanges(userForm)">
      Gender: 
        <select
          name="gender"
          ng-model="user.gender"
          ng-change="getChanges(userForm)">
            <option value="M">M</option>
            <option value="F">F</option>
            <option value="O">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button
        name="reset"
        type="button"
        ng-click="setPristine(userForm)">Set pristine
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div>
    User changed values: {{ changedValues | json }}
  </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    user: {
      name: null,
      age: null,
      gender: null
    },
    changedValues: {},
    getChanges: function(form) {
      $scope.changedValues = {};
      angular.forEach(form, function(value, key) {
        if (!key.startsWith('$')) {
          if (value.$dirty) {
            $scope.changedValues[key] = value.$modelValue;
          }
        }
      });
    },
    setPristine: function(form) {
      form.$setPristine();
      $scope.getChanges(form);
    }
  });

  $timeout($scope.reset);
});
```

---

[image: img]